# How to fit ion-slides and button in the same page in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
<ion-content >
    <ion-slides loop #Slides>
        <ion-slide >
            <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide >
            <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide >
            <h2>Slide 3</h2>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
    <button ion-button full>login</button>
</ion-content>
```

When I use the code above, I have to scroll down to see the button.
Is there any way to force all the components to be on the same page ?

Comment: Yes your answer worked ! thanks robbannn

Comment: Please give an upvote if you found my answer useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your page SCSS:

```
.scroll-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    ion-slides {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```